# Motherboard and RAM compatibility

Tags: memory, upgrade, compatibility

My computer often freezes for few seconds when doing memory intensive operations, cause of 1 GB installed memory. Windows 7 starts to use Paging File but my hard drive is very slow and opening a basic game or application could take some seconds. ReadyBoost with 4 GB cache boosted the OS but that isn't a solution.

So I went to shop to buy another stick of 1 GB memory. My motherboard is [Gigabyte GA-945PL-S3](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=2325#ov) and it supports DRR2 memory, up to 4 GB with 4 slots.

The shopman said that 1 GB of DDR2 memory is very rare and that they don't sell them anymore (absurd, few days ago there was a few sticks of 1GB memory). There was only sticks with 2 GB memory, but I didn't want to buy so much memory. But then shopman pulled out a stick of RAM from old computer, I had to buy it anyways. The memory wasn't brand new (the Everest doesn't show module name of this stick) but it did a job. Now I have 2 GB memory (2/4 slots) and no problems with performance.

But I don't think my motherboard supports more then 1 GB memory on each slot, because if it would then the max memory limit wouldn't be 4 GB. Am I right, should I buy 2 GB memory instead of 1 GB?

*Apologies for my english*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. Your motherboard does not support 2GB sticks.